# Memory leak Micrometer java

Tags: java, memory-leaks, micrometer

I analyzed my heap dump by uploading on an online website and am getting this

```
 Java Static io.micrometer.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ObjectCleaner.LIVE_SET
```

Object might be causing memory leak.

```
115,297K (23.4%) of char[]
Java Static 
io.micrometer.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ObjectCleaner.LIVE_SET
io.micrometer.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ConcurrentSet.map
{java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap}.keys
 io.micrometer.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ObjectCleaner$AutomaticCleanerReference.referent
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread.threadLocals
j.l.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap.table
j.l.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap$Entry[]
j.l.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap$Entry.value
j.l.r.SoftReference.referent
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.BufferRecycler._charBuffers
char[][]
```

Any suggestions regarding this?

Comment: Which Netty version are you using?

Comment: Micrometer version is 1.0.6

Comment: Could you provide a sample and steps to reproduce it?

Comment: maybe make it a github issue in the micrometer project.
https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues